# Defining a variable when running a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, variables, sh

I'm trying to write a shell script which basically goes into a particular folder and performs some actions. The catch here is that the folder name is variable i.e. `/path/to/variable`

I was thinking, is it possible to run a shell script from command line and also define a variable in the same line? Something like:

```
./run.sh $id=456
```

When it runs, it takes the path as
`/path/to/$id` and hence `/path/to/456`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the script in the following style:

```
./run.sh 465
```

Than you can access the content of the parameter inside the script with `$1` (1st parameter), `$2` (2nd parameter) and so on.
To change the directory use `cd /path/to/$1`
BTW: `$#` returns the count of parameters.

Another way is to use arguments, like here: http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/118031
So you can run your script like this: `./run.sh -d 465` (where -d stand for directory)

Comment: ...because it was in easy question? Does the answer fits your needs?

Answer (score 3):

Other way around.

```
id=456 ./run.sh
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth explaining that this automatically exports the variable `id` with the value `456` to the script `run.sh` (and only to that script and any programs it runs; not to anything run after it).